# Map in intranet

Tags: dictionary

Anybody knows about how to show maps offline through a web application. Actually the application hosted in intranet with out any internet connection. We have to implement a feature that uses maps to show the location.

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at Google Maps for Business (http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/).

Comment: Ken, For using google, we have to connect with google map to access api. do they provide their data for intranet setup by any licensing mode?

Comment: I read from Google that their enterprise solution was made for systems running in intranet. I didn't dream that the server can also disconnect from the world, but no need for clients.